# Is it possible? (To show specified methods, depending on a given parameter.)

Tags: visual-studio, call

I have a (binary)reader, to read DBC files (Its a file format used by a game) into structures, that I know. Every DBC file differs a little bit (their structs), from the others, and their reading method differs too. (there is spell.dbc item.dbc map.dbc etc...)
So I made unique reading methods for all the DBC files I want to read. (I think its not the best solution, but for now, its okey for me.)

Here Is an example usage:

```
DBCReader reader = new DBCReader(DBCFile.Spell); // you can use DBCFile.Map or others here
```

Now my question : **Is that possible to list only the spell related methods, when I use my reader?**

So my DBCReader class contains different reading methods, for all the dbc files,and I would like to only see the spell related ones.

So now when I write "reader." to C#, it lists all my methods for all dbc files, like

- ReadMapName() (which is for Map.dbc),
  ReadSpellID() (which is for
  Spell.dbc),  GetItemName() (which is
  for Item.dbc) etc..

**But I only want the spell related methods to be listed**. Is it possible? :) 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to get intellisense to display a subset of the methods in a class.

You could make seperate classes for each type, ie:

dbcSpellreader, dbcMapReader, etc.